# Copy a folder in Alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco, nodereference

I want to copy a folder into another, in Alfresco, recursively, with Java.

I only have the NodeRef of each folder.

How to do?

Answer (score 2):

Use [CopyService.copyAndRename](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/org/alfresco/service/cmr/repository/CopyService.html#copyAndRename-org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef-org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef-org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName-org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName-boolean-):

```
copyService.copyAndRename(
    sourceNodeRef,
    destinationNodeRef,
    ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS,
    QName.createQName(NamespaceService.CONTENT_MODEL_1_0_URI, "New name"),
    true // Recursive
);
```

Inspired from Alfresco's own [ScriptNode.java](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition-old/blob/master/projects/repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/jscript/ScriptNode.java#L2127).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody is looking for copying file(s) from to destination folder in alfresco:

```
String docName = nodeService.getProperty(fileNode, ContentModel.PROP_NAME).toString();
QName documentName = QName.createQName(CustomModel.CUSTOM_NAMESPACE_URI,docName);
NodeRef copiedFile = copyService.copy(fileNode, destnode, ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS, documentName);

nodeService.setProperty(copiedFile, ContentModel.PROP_NAME, docName);
```

The last line sets the copied file name to actual document name; else you will find the copied file name as noderef of the file

Comment: Your answer describes how to copy a single file in Alfresco, right?

Comment: Yes, if we want to copy multiple files, we can loop over the files' list:    
 for (NodeRef fileNode : list) { //the code that I posted }